# can't clone git repos via http; info/refs not found

Tags: git, http, repository, clone, git-bare

I am trying to make a git repository available for read-only access over http.

I am doing it the old-style way because `git-http-backend` is not available on my host system.  That is, I am simply putting the bare repository in a http accessible location.

I created the bare repository successfully on the host using `git clone --bare <some-remote-location>`.

Now, when I point git to the new clone using `git clone http://my.host.name/location`, a message reports `repository not found`.

When I capture network traffic, I see that git is attempting to access `http://my.host.name/location/info/refs`.  This would be expected to fail because there is no `info/refs` path in the repository. Rather there are `info` and `refs` directories directly beneath the repository root.

Evidently the cloned bare repository is not structured as expected by the client.  Does anyone know why this might be?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You will need to run [`git update-server-info`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-server-info.html) on the server to generate the files necessary for the “dumb protocol” to work.

Comment: Additionally, you need to do this in a bare repository

Answer (score 10):

Try the steps mentioned [here on git-scm for http/s protocol](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols).

Basically, after doing the `git clone --bare <path-to-repository>`, you need to run `mv hooks/post-update.sample hooks/post-update` withing your bare repository and then do a `git update-server-info` once and then you should be able to clone the repo.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this issue when the remote is running on a git repository 1.7.X and the git client is 1.8.X ; I proved it by downgrading my client to 1.7.X - this fixed the issue. So make sure git is the same version on "client" and "server" sides. The command I was running was git clone  .

Comment: I had the same issue, and it turned out to be because the server was sending charset=utf-8. see https://github.com/takezoe/gitbucket/issues/20

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error trying to clone a **gitlab project** because I set a wrong path !
I took the `SSH` path instead of the `HTTP` path. (+ do not forget the `.git`)

```
git clone *HTTP_path.git*
```

Answer (score -1):

Remember also to check that the required modules are enable on apache. These are the required modules for git over HTTP:

- mod_alias
- mod_cgi
- mod_env